# Help me choose the right open source licence

Tags: open-source, licensing

I am writing a project in php and planning to release it soon as open source.

The problem is that it uses 5 external classes, all of which are also open source but have different licences.

I need your help to pick the licence that would be compatable with all these external classes.

Here is what I am using:

1. Pear Pager | Licence: BSD http://www.debian.org/misc/bsd.license
2. Pear Event_Dispatcher: Licence BSD http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
3. HN Captcha: GNU GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.html)
4. Zend_ACL, license: http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd
5. GeoIP class by MaxMind, licence: LGPL http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.txt

So, which licence should I release my project under and still be able to include all these external libraries?

Also, is it possible to add a small 'requirement' to the license to require those who use it to always add a "no nofollow" link "powered by So and so" ?

Please answer only if you know for sure. Thanks for your help

Comment: See also:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8034/license-requirements-for-including-open-source-software

Comment: Thanks but that question does not really have a definitive answer. I hope someone can answer my question so I can proceed with releasing my project soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on http://freshmeat.net/projects/hn_captcha/ HN Captcha appears to use LGPL. If that is true, then you can use any license you wish (including a proprietary license). Otherwise GPL is the only option.

Comment: Thanks. I turns out I was still using the old version 1.3 which has GPL licence and their new version 1.5 is LGPL. This is good news for me.

Comment: Indeed. GPL for a captcha generator is anyway a bit ridiculous. But LGPL requries dynamic linking.

Answer (score 1):

GPL, you can't use your captcha library otherwise.

Comment: The version of the GPL of the library you use. And I don't mean LGPL.

Comment: Since the newer version is LGPL, the above comment is wrong.